# Switching Drupal form widgets based on flash detection

Tags: php, javascript, flash, drupal, file-upload

I have a problem. I have a client where some of their employees have flash installed and some don't. So always using the swfuploader module widget isn't going to work and it doesn't gracefully fall back to HTML. In fact it just leaves a non-functioning button in its wake.

So what I would like to do is detect when they don't have Flash available and switch to the standard Drupal File Upload widget. Now in my head it seems like this would only work if done on the server-side. But can that even be done reliably on the server side?

Also, can this on-the-fly widget switching even work in Drupal or will it pitch a fit?

By the way, I am using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I also addressed this in [Using multiple form field widgets for the same field in Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466895/using-multiple-form-field-widgets-for-the-same-field-in-drupal)

What I ended up doing was creating a second form field that uses the filefield upload widget and loaded it on the form alongside the Flash widget. Then I put JS on the page that detects if Flash is on the page and is of the correct version. If it is found then it hides the html/AJAX uploader. If it is not then it hides the Flash uploader.