# Using multiple form field widgets for the same field in Drupal

Tags: php, forms, drupal, widget, cck

I would like to be able to use multiple form field widgets for the same field and to be able to switch it based on session data from the user. But I am not really sure how to accomplish this. This is for Drupal 6. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I should add that I am doing this as a fallback for a Flash uploader for when Flash is not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a second form field that uses the filefield upload widget and loaded it on the form alongside the Flash widget. Then I put JS on the page that detects if Flash is on the page and is of the correct version. If it is found then it hides the html/AJAX uploader. If it is not then it hides the Flash uploader.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to accomplish this with one of the field access modules but to do it properly you'd probably need to create a custom widget. Your widgets can return existing widgets by calling their handles, so your widget would more or less be a wrapper that returns the correct widget call.

[this tutorial](http://maxeydevbox.org/blogs/geoffmaxey/building-custom-compound-fieldswidgets-cck-drupal-6x) gives a pretty good overview of widget creation in Drupal 6.

Comment: I will take a look at this. I have been thinking that since I have to do some Flash detection in JavaScript on form load, I might be able to load the HTML widget with AJAX. Either way I am looking for as much info as possible.